# BLE scanning not working on android 10 with permissions

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am an android beginner and I am trying to make an app that connects with a ble device and communicates with it. To connect to it I first need to find the device, which I do with lescanner. App is working fine with older versions of android but is not starting scanning with the new android 10.
I have a problem which is that I cannot debug the device because of the only android 10 phone that I can use is not mine and is not near me all the time. I saw that there is others with the same problem on android 10 and their problems were always those with permissions which I feel I covered. What am I doing wrong?
I have added all required permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Here is how i ask for permissions on onCreate:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                        builder.setTitle("This app needs background location access");
                        builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect your device in the background.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                }
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                builder.setTitle("This app needs fine location and background location access");
                builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect your device.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
                    }
                });
                builder.show();

            }
        }else
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Android M Permission check
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                builder.setTitle("This app needs coarse location access");
                builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect your device.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")) {
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"},1 );
            }
        }
```

And here is my code for scanning:

```
    public void scanBTLEDevices ( final boolean enable){
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner() == null) {
            Log.d("BTLE", "Bluetooth adapter or scanner were null!");
            return;
        }
        if (enable) {
            Log.i(TAG, "scanBTLEDevices: Scanning started!");
            List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
            filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString("00001813-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).build());
            ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setReportDelay(0).setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters, settings,scanCallback);//filters, settings
            Toast.makeText(this,"Scanning started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(scanCallback);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Scanning stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Scanning stopped");
        }
    }
    private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();

            if (device.getName() == null) {
                return;
            }

            Log.i(TAG,"Scanner found:"+device.getName());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Scanner found something",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(!scannedDevices.contains(device.getName()) && device.getName()!=null) {
                if (device.getName().equals(DEVICE_NAME)) {
                    if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
                        scanBTLEDevices(false);
                        mDeviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            switch (errorCode){
                case ScanCallback.SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED:
                    Log.i(TAG,"onScanFailed: SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED");
                case ScanCallback.SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "onScanFailed: SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED");
                case ScanCallback.SCAN_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "onScanFailed: SCAN_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED");
                case ScanCallback.SCAN_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                    Log.i(TAG, "onScanFailed: SCAN_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR");
                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, "onScanFailed: unknown error code");
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried Kotlin?